# Adding an UIButton inside an UITextField

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to add a button with text "..." inside my UITextField. What i'm trying is the following:

```
@IBOutlet weak var requestTitleTxtField: UITextField!
```

viewDidLoad():

```
var detailsButton = UIButton()
detailsButton.titleLabel!.text = "..."
requestTitleTxtField.rightViewMode = UITextFieldViewMode.Always
requestTitleTxtField.rightView = detailsButton
```

This is not returning any error message but isn't showing the button either.

Comment: try setting the frame property of the UIButton

Comment: Why not add some text in a button?

Comment: Thats exactly what im trying. @MSU_Bulldog already tried it.

Comment: Have you tried requestTxtField addSubview:detailsButton and setting frame property of UIButton instead of doing requestTitleTxtField.rightView?  Also I'm not sure about Swift, but are you including the UITextFieldDelegate in your class? in Objective-C you would just do @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextFieldDelegate>

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create the button with frame:

```
var detailsButton = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 24, height: 24))
```

Use `detailsButton.setTitle("...", forState: .Normal)` to set the title.

You may also need to set color for the text:

```
detailsButton.setTitleColor(UIColor.redColor(), forState: .Normal)
```